# React/Typescript error when adding promise to a function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ethereum, decentralized-applications

I am using the following function from useWagmi to write a transaction to an ethereum contract: https://wagmi.sh/docs/hooks/useContractWrite

```
const [{ data, error, loading }, write] = useContractWrite(
    {
      addressOrName: 'Address',
      contractInterface: Interface,
    },
    'publicSaleMint',
    {
      args: [thirdHashRef.current],
    }
  )
```

**This has worked perfectly**. However, I want to return the transaction response after the transaction is sent - I followed the documentation and added a promise to the end of the transaction:

```
const [{ data, error, loading }, write] = useContractWrite(
    {
      addressOrName: 'Address',
      contractInterface: Interface,
    },
    'publicSaleMint',
    {
      args: [hashRef.current],
    }
  )=> Promise<{ data?: TransactionResponse, error?: Error }> **Added this**
```

And am calling the function here:

```
async function handleSubmit() {
    await cleanEntries()
      .then(() => { write() })
      .then((data) => { console.log(data.TransactionResponse) })
  }
```

However, now I am getting the following errors:

```
Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'PromiseConstructor' and '{ data: any; error: ErrorConstructor; }'.ts(2365)

Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and '() => Promise<void>'.ts(2365)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you mention says this:

> ### Return Values
>
> write
>
> ```
> (
>   config: {
>     args: any | any[]
>     overrides?: Overrides
>   } = {},
> ) => Promise<{ data?: TransactionResponse; error?: Error }>
> ```

That documentation is not telling you to write that code, it's just showing you the arguments and the type of the return value. This is a fragment of a function declaration where the part after the `=>` is the return type of the function. This is written by the library author, and you don't need to add it.

So the `write` function returned by `useContractWrite` already returns a promise, all you have to do is use it. You don't need to add any special syntax.

```
const [{ data, error, loading }, write] = useContractWrite(/* ... */)
write().then(() => console.log('promise resolved'))
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDCEB2MoCGAxjAOpTAzpwC+cAZlBCHAOQDuBA5iMKwLAAoIUVyp4ASTzoo9YugBccAjgCecALyIaIsfBgALYFAAmACQKoDAJXT1NiOEWRQo6PEtYEARkVa0hXRxxOABtJBMCGAIAGjgZJig4gBsIAhNgHC5aOPYKKgBdBzQsXHxiMnz0AAohOHrEOob69JM3VFQAeSgAOQIQRTYAQRM29A7WGKbm0TxCEikqWXklRZk5InQpwWaabebWMGRvZOAiAGUCZPQAWUyYSenGneblKC5UJVDDY3NLGzsADpnK53DACvsGjoXgBKQKCAD0CLgmCuyTgeUoNRhyhwJjgIAIAGtqCU4BB7IZqG4YC4cOh8WAmLwMIChJiqNUYYCqThqlzNAA+JxiCDXQGpLjVQ7M4AYODtMUANwZrBhMKAA)